# PHP Extends Class

Tags: php, class

Goodmorning everyone.
I coded a class that return me:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Test Vari/index.php on line 12
Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Test Vari/index.php on line 12
```

This is the first part of the php file:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['ID'] = 1;
require_once 'pass/password.inc.php'; /*Here's the DB Class*/
```

I extended a class into another, here's the code:

```
class pg extends DB{
   public $id;
   function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->id = $_SESSION['ID'];
   }
   public function pgname(){
      $rs = $db->row("SELECT CONCAT(Nome, ' ', Cognome) FROM Personaggio WHERE id = :id",array("id"=>$this->id));
      return($rs);
  }
}
 $pg = new pg(); 
 print_r ( $pg->pgname());
```

The $db->row() is declared in DB class that I extended, and I know for sure that's working.
The DB class isn't initialized, and when I do, the error is the same, this is how I do it:

```
class pg extends DB{
    public $id;
    public $db;
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = new DB();
        $this->id = $_SESSION['ID'];
    }
    public function pgname(){
        $rs = $db->row("SELECT CONCAT(Nome, ' ', Cognome) FROM Personaggio WHERE id = :id",array("id"=>$this->id));
        return($rs);
    }
}
```

The Fatal Error will disappear when I delete braces in `print_r($pg->pgname);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way is just fine, but you need to remember that you are calling `$db->row(` as it exists in the parent class you need to use `$this->` on it so

```
class pg extends DB{
   public $id;
   function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->id = $_SESSION['ID'];
   }
   public function pgname(){
      $rs = $this->row("SELECT CONCAT(Nome, ' ', Cognome) FROM Personaggio WHERE id = :id",array("id"=>$this->id));
      return($rs);
  }
}

$pg = new pg(); 
print_r ( $pg->pgname());
```

Also to keep the encapsulation of the class nice and tight, it would be better to pass the session to the constructor rather than get it from the $_SESSION inside the constructor like this :

```
class pg extends DB{
   public $id;
   function __construct($id){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->id = $id;
   }
   public function pgname(){
      $rs = $this->row("SELECT CONCAT(Nome, ' ', Cognome) FROM Personaggio WHERE id = :id",array("id"=>$this->id));
      return($rs);
  }
}

$pg = new pg($_SESSION['ID']); 
print_r ( $pg->pgname());
```

I also assume you have included the file containing the `DB` class?

Comment: Yes, like this:
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['ID'] = 1;
require_once 'pass/password.inc.php';

Comment: public function pgname($id){
      $rs = $this->db->row("SELECT CONCAT(Nome, ' ', Cognome) FROM Personaggio WHERE ID = :id",array("id"=>$id));
      return($rs);
  }
$pg = new pg();
echo($pg->pgname($_SESSION['ID']));

Still don't work, this is the output:

Notice: Undefined property: pg::$db in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Test Vari/index.php on line 9
Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Test Vari/index.php on line 9

Comment: Read my answer `$rs = $this->row("....` NOT `$this->db->row(` You dont need the `db` as you have extended the DB class all the class is seen as a single entity

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, I forgot to deleted it, thank you alot, so nice from you!
Sorry for my misunderstooding.

Answer (score 0):

you have to require_once 'DB.php'

Comment: I forgot to put it but it's here:
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['ID'] = 1;
require_once 'pass/password.inc.php';